# Translate a simple sentence from Toki Pona

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

[Toki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toki_Pona) [Pona](http://tokipona.net/tp/janpije/okamasona.php) is a linguist's code golf: A minimalist language with a vocabulary of around 120 words. Because of this, it has very few grammatical irregularities found in other languages, making it ideal for a code golf challenge.

Your task is to take the most simple form of a Toki Pona sentence and translate it into English, using the (even more) limited dictionary provided in this question.

### The dictionary

While 120 words isn't a lot for a language, it's a lot of bytes. So, for that reason, I'm limiting the input to only contain these 20 words (English translation in brackets, Toki Pona in **bold**):

- Pronouns: **mi** (I/me), **sina** (you) and **ona** (he/she/it/him/her)
- Grammatical constructs: **li** and **e**
- Verbs: **jo** (to have), **moku** (to eat), **pona** (to fix), **oko** (to see) and **wile** (to want)
- Adjectives: **pona** (good/simple), **ike** (bad), **wan** (one/unique) and **mute** (many)
- Nouns: **kili** (fruit), **oko** (eye), **jan** (person/man/woman), **moku** (food), **ilo** (tool) and **ijo** (thing)

In addition, sentences involving the verb *to be* are included (expanded on later).

As you can see, simple sentences such as **I want food** can be made from this list: **mi wile e moku**. We'll address the exact grammatical construction in the next section. However, note that a single word may be used for multiple different English words (e.g. **moku**), which is how such a limited vocabulary is possible.

### Grammar

All of the sentences you'll be required to handle will have one of the following forms:

- **pronoun/noun "li" verb**

  - e.g. **ona li oko** (he sees)
- **pronoun/noun "li" pronoun/noun**

  - e.g. **ona li jan** (she is a person)
- **pronoun/noun "li" noun adjective**

  - e.g. **ona li ijo ike** (it is a bad thing)
- **pronoun/noun "li" verb "e" pronoun/noun**

  - e.g. **jan li jo e kili** (the person has fruit)
- **pronoun/noun "li" verb "e" noun adjective**

  - e.g. **jan li jo e kili pona** (the person has good fruit)

We'll call the first **pronoun/noun** the *subject* of the sentence and the second the *object*. Notice that the adjective comes after the noun, not before, and that pronouns cannot be paired with adjectives.

For example, **ona li moku e moku** (He eats food) is of the fourth form. However, the one exception is that if the subject is **mi** (I/me) or **sina** (you), then **li** is omitted. So **mi moku e moku** would translate as I eat food.

You'll notice that forms 2 and 3 don't have a verb, but our translated examples do. This is because Toki Pona has no word for *to be*. While we would say "I am good", Toki Pona speakers would say **mi pona** instead (omitting the verb). If the subject is not **mi** or **sina**, then **li** is used as it would be usually: **kili li moku**.

The two constructs **li** and **e** are used in the following ways:

- If the pronoun preceding is not **mi** or **sina**, the verb in the sentence is preceded by **li**. For example, **moku li moku** or **ona li oko**
- The object in the sentence is always preceded by **e**. For example, **moku li moku e moku** or **mi pona e ilo mute**.

Notice that Toki Pona doesn't conjugate verbs, nor does it change the word when plural. Due to this, you should assume that all input is in the singular (**ijo** is translated as **thing**, not **things**)

### English translation

In comparison, all outputted sentences should be in the forms

- **pronoun/noun verb**
- **pronoun/noun verb pronoun/noun**
- **pronoun/noun verb adjective pronoun/noun**

As each word has multiple translations (**ona** is he, she or it), we'll use these translations:

```
mi   (subject)   -> I
mi   (object)    -> me
sina             -> you
ona  (subject)   -> he
ona  (object)    -> him
jo               -> to have
moku (verb)      -> to eat
moku (noun)      -> food
pona (verb)      -> to fix
pona (adjective) -> good
oko  (verb)      -> to see
oko  (noun)      -> eye
wile             -> to want
ike              -> bad
wan              -> one
mute             -> many
kili             -> fruit
jan              -> person
ilo              -> tool
ijo              -> thing
```

However, because English has plenty of grammatical irregularities, and we have such a small vocabulary list, the English output should be as accurate as possible. Therefore:

- Verbs in English are to be conjugated. This means that for all verbs except *to be*:

  - The **I** and **you** forms are the same as the infinitive (to fix -> I fix, you fix etc.)
  - The *he* form (which includes nouns) modifies the infinitive to end with an `s`. Specfically, the 5 verbs become **has**, **eats**, **fixes**, **sees** and **wants** respectively.
- For *to be*, **I** becomes **am**, **you** becomes **are** and **he** (including nouns) become **is**
- Nouns are prefixed with a `the`  (notice the space), unless the adjective after it is **wan** (one) or **mute** (many).
- Nouns before **mute** (many) should have a trailing `s` (yes even **fruit** and **food**). So **ilo mute** becomes **many tools**

### Your task

You are to take in a single sentence of Toki Pona consisting of only words from those 20, and always in one of the forms listed above (including the *to be* exceptions), and output the English translation. As is standard in Toki Pona, input will always be lowercase.

You may take input where the separator is any consistent non-alphabetic character or sequence of characters, including spaces (i.e. `mi@@@e@@@jan` is perfectly acceptable), or you may take input as a list of words, if you wish. The input does not have to make sense (e.g. **ijo li jo e jan mute**), but will always follow the grammatical rules.

Output rules are equally lax - you may output as a list of words, or as a single string with any consistent, non-alphabetical separator. Case is irrelevant.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins!

### Test cases

```
mi wile e moku - I want the food
mi moku e moku - I eat the food
mi pona - I fix+
mi jan - I am the person
ona li oko - He sees/He is the eye*
ona li jan - He is the person
ona li ijo ike - He is the bad thing
jan li jo e kili - The person has the fruit
jan li oko e kili pona - The person sees the good fruit
kili li moku - The fruit is the food/The fruit eats*
moku li moku - The food is the food/The food eats*
moku li moku e moku - The food eats the food
ijo li jo e jan mute - The thing has many persons
ilo li pona e ijo - The tool fixes the thing
sina moku e kili mute - You eat many fruits
sina moku e kili ike - You eat the bad fruit
oko li oko e mi - The eye sees me
mi wile e sina - I want you
jan li moku e ona - The person eats him
mi jo e ijo wan - I have one thing
mi jo e ijo mute - I have many things
sina kili - you are the fruit

*: Either translation is acceptable for output, as both are valid translations
+: I am good would be the natural translation, but using pona as an adjective doesn't fix as one of our five forms, so is not a valid translation in this case
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18187/66833). I have aimed to be as comprehensive as possible with the test cases, but please comment if you would like any more/a specific test case

Comment: "Pronouns: mi (I/me), sina (you) and ona (he/she/it/him/her)" Just hope that this question doesn't fall afoul of the Code of Conduct and get us all suspended.

Comment: 'I am good' shouldn't be included, because it's a **noun/pronoun "li" adjective**, the schema is not listed above

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin It is, but in this case the **li** is omitted, as the pronoun is **mi**. I thought it would be better to have an single exception to the rule, rather than list an additional 5 rules just to cover **mi/sina**.

Comment: I see, I mean other thing: only **noun**, **verb**, **pronoun** is allowed after **"li"** even if **"li"** is omitted, but here is **adjective** after **"li"** in 'I am good'.

Comment: Also why isn't 'you' capitalized in the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I understand now, yes you are correct, **mi pona** doesn't fit any form when **pona** is used as an adjective. I've fixed the test case, and added a note about that specific case. The **you** wasn't capitalised due to a typo - it has now been fixed.

Comment: The list of test cases translated into English read like the lyrics of some '70s Talking Heads song. Same as it ever was!

Comment: @Arnauld Added, thanks!

Comment: @Arnauld Ah yes, my bad

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>498 ... 447</s>  445 bytes

Outputs in lowercase, except for `'I'`.

```javascript
s=>(s.replace(/\w+/g,w=>(x='2want||2eat/5food||5you|2see/5eye|5thing|1I/4me|5person|8many|8bad|5fruit|1he/4him|5tool||2fix/8good||2have||8one'.split`|`[n=parseInt(w,35)%781%21])&&(x=(g=_=>x.split`/`.find(x=>x[0]>>t&1,t++)||g())(),o[t]=x.slice(1),O[t]=n),o=[t=-1],O=[]))&&([s,v,o,a]=o,[S,V,O,A]=O,g=n=>4241>>n&1?'':'the ')(S)+s+` ${y=144>>S&1,1/V?V^17|y?v:'ha':S^4?S^7?'i':'am':'are'}${y?'':V^15?'s':'es'} `+g(A%10^9&&O)+[a&&a+' ']+[o]+['s'[A^9]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZVLb@IwFIX3/RVWNc1DSUnDgEorJai7YcWCUTeZMHiKCS6JjXB4qe5vZ65NIDySFglQLJ/P1@ceO@94hcXbgs7ze8bHZDcJdiIILdFYkHmK34jl/Vk7XuKuYXATmM01ZrmUTYJzrz3hfCxle8uXsikI8dpkS2Q7n1KWSL/ntTJ4mpOF4Ex2Msy2svMPj2V7sljSXPpT4rWmNAMB5ykgJ3TjdRKNbE7xikjZ4YyYDTFPaT6So4gFc7wQpMdya@3@bNt3jx3/runHtmFAaVYS/A3CTTHdGzUmlI1hPNxED3EY5obv5o5jS5lYtm3ZLo/yOIDpKYVN@rbbV88MxoMoD@792O0HUWwrdiTclctdHAfcjQbuq9t3X@Kg7yYBC8JWs@WHITP8rmk@m/mUINO2BrYjnBH68bEN/FYrDAewuO@9dl@H/qPcdlfP5hSbz4NhqzsYPnZNCkqcqZ8FMT9BpVgwt901BYwSYX6ikZNYL3f@w/DJMPq2E2HDwI6JzNiJOHxhYvQyfIrj3RtngqekkfLEmli3GUVrmhJEUMZny1vbRseP56EeUv1EqmzVzJtrsVLViiEFX2nnnOEz0akWZ0g12@shaHyF@B2zKu1RrNbdh@tSDKuilCI@41cAEP8iCLIqPPinQlMgtTWIqhr2iEL6ZQH0nSM6I5e2lWo4DUiflksArKuX5@D8jKb0BAGA38eF0RTvSfpI1VDAhwJTNuScovzQGNWQapaWp/Q6B0eWlh12pgLhlaOQE3HVYhWsr4mqmiugGvyOdxHYU56S1mZWdezgu3IvW@aH9hUM3S5tu7rQCgOvaqGp5ii7gQTUcoMHDtx5KviF8ZUpEBTkxXa0/2U5QIFbV58/XYe2WXwLKNN4AjgksbLvKjzHDGWnQTzsBE7PPkAZuam9e1QlNXcPlFET3KLys0vkPLi6mfAOqbo@@N55tchF1T2kXi/ArfH9VH2SgHO1tl3Lq22/OLalXtkO93x5bHf/AQ)

#### How?

We first split the input string \$s\$ into words and interpret each of them as an integer in base \$35\$, modulo \$781\$ and modulo \$21\$, which gives a unique ID \$n\$ in \$[0..19]\$. We associate a data string to each ID as follows:

```
 word   | base 35 to decimal | mod 781 | mod 21 | data
--------+--------------------+---------+--------+--------------
 'mi'   |                788 |       7 |      7 | '1I/4me'
 'sina' |            1223365 |     319 |      4 | '5you'
 'ona'  |              30215 |     537 |     12 | '1he/4him'
 'jo'   |                689 |     689 |     17 | '2have'
 'moku' |             973380 |     254 |      2 | '2eat/5food'
 'pona' |            1102090 |      99 |     15 | '2fix/8good'
 'oko'  |              30124 |     446 |      5 | '2see/5eye'
 'wile' |            1394799 |     714 |      0 | '2want'
 'ike'  |              22764 |     115 |     10 | '8bad'
 'wan'  |              39573 |     523 |     19 | '8one'
 'mute' |             981029 |      93 |      9 | '8many'
 'kili' |             880303 |     116 |     11 | '5fruit'
 'jan'  |              23648 |     218 |      8 | '5person'
 'ilo'  |              22809 |     160 |     13 | '5tool'
 'ijo'  |              22739 |      90 |      6 | '5thing'
 'li'   |                753 |     753 |     18 | ''
 'e'    |                 14 |      14 |     14 | ''
```

We keep track of the expected type of the next word in the variable \$t\$:

- \$t=0\$: subject
- \$t=1\$: verb
- \$t=2\$: object
- \$t=3\$: adjective

The leading digit in front of each translated word is a bitmask describing the types that the word can be associated with. For instance, `"5fruit"` means that `"fruit"` may be either the *subject* (\$2^0=1\$) or the *object* (\$2^2=4\$) of the sentence.

We use this information to assign the relevant type to each input word. At the end of this process, the array `[s,v,o,a]` holds the categorized words (subject, verb, object and adjective, respectively) while the array `[S,V,O,A]` holds the corresponding indices, as described in the penultimate column of the above table.

Using these variables, we can finally apply English rules to translate the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 1902 bytes

```python
import re
p='mi|sina|ona'
v='jo|moku|pona|oko|wile'
a='pona|ike|wan|mute'
n='kili|oko|jan|moku|ilo|ijo'
pn=p+'|'+n
d={'p':p,'v':v,'a':a,'n':n,'pn':pn,'li':'li','e':'e',
   'f':'(?:(?:'+pn+') li|(?:mi|sina))'}
g=['f '+i for i in 'v,pn,n a,v e pn,v e n a'.split(',')]
ma=[re.compile('^%s$'%re.subn(r'\w+',lambda m:'({%s})'%m.group(0),i)[0].format(**d))
    for i in g]
tr0=lambda ph:[m.match(ph) and m.match(ph).groups() for m in ma]
d_={'s':{'mi':'I','sina':'you','ona':'he'},'o':{'mi':'me','sina':'you','ona':'him'},'v':{'jo':'have','moku':'eat','pona':'fix','oko':'see','wile':'want'},'n':{'moku':'food','oko':'eye','kili':'fruit','jan':'person','ilo':'tool','ijo':'thing'},'a':{'pona':'good','ike':'bad','wan':'one','mute':'many'}}
md=lambda x:dict((k,v) for i in x for k,v in d_[i].items())
d_['pn']=md('on')
d_['f']=md('sn')
d_['e']={'e':'_'}
mc=lambda x:lambda t:(lambda d:d[t] if t in d else d['_'])(x)
be=mc({'I':'am','you':'are','_':'is'})
vs=lambda p:list(d_[p].values())
os=vs('o')+vs('s')
tr=lambda x:[(n_,[d_[p][w if n else w.split(' ')[0]] \
              for n,(w,p) in enumerate(zip(i,pt.split(' ')))]) \
             for n_,(i,pt) in enumerate(zip(x,g)) if i]
noun=lambda t:lambda n:n if n in os else t+n
the=noun('the ')
the2=lambda n:'' if n in os else 'the '
v_=mc({'I':'','you':'','_':'s'})
m_=lambda o,a:('s' if (a == 'many') and (o not in os) else '')
tr_={0:lambda n,v:[the(n),
                   v+v_(n)],
     3:lambda s,v,e,o:[the(s),v+v_(s),the(o)],
     1:lambda s,o:[the(s),be(s),the(o)],
     2:lambda s,o,a:[the(s),be(s),the2(o)+a,o+m_(o,a)],
     4:lambda s,v,e,o,a:[the(s),v+v_(s),the2(o)+a,o+m_(o,a)],
     }
from functools import reduce
f_={'haves':'has','fixs':'fixes','the one':'one','the many':'many'}
fx=lambda s:reduce(lambda x,y:x.replace(y[0],y[1]),f_.items(),s)
c=lambda s:s[0].upper()+s[1:]
r=lambda s:[(n,c(fx(' '.join(tr_[n](*a))))) for n,a in tr(tr0(s))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVXbbuM4DH33V@hhC0qNELSdfTJg7PN@g8cTqLGcqIkusGQnmSbf3iVlJynaHaOoSOqQOuJFCae09e7Hx0dhbPB9Yr0uQgXWnKNx6uydgmKs4M2frd8N5@DJuPPng9lrKFQF2WJ2@nxQ7myHhFZXwc7sTca9kZU8zd6fzZuHIrgqLOAMC1e01TsEKIOEEcpRgoJSSXBQOgkBl4Dr3kBJ/yRoFDTIgjEGHcr8nxL/YBHcAgTD81CbeQsBl2JT1dAxWBjW@Z4ZZhyDUWJMx5QcmWYo0oIqLGPYm8TxFNEUVlV1r5drbwPeksOvh/gXPKAlDq@O9/DzsAC5V/a1Vcwij/eHeBHwYJeb3g@BPwlpRP3ULPFYqxJ/fGyFINZ3HpumSP1TNccI27K2S4SutzxsBVOuZZ/0KWzkIvtb8reqKdoVZi9C@Y7Fwmz8i9zp6iie/ICKz/JWwwXlG8zqP@CMJeBIQKwSGtRIUKod5V0lVMKE7cyR/HYEi5pQuRtKwBZIFMXl4ybPzvv2htYnQlNz0E4/GIqKLYJa0H30DlVsFFST93tSMpe0NW5DgRUFnllspsDYeqi8KpIPOZJ3mTi1It5XuRNcLoVtr9k@lq1ZJ853chT3ihyziDZS2lVtmqVJ2mLWBWa6pnZsKttyjA6TpZsN8WrQaHjPXbrC7rPr@4GzkEo@S23Z1qlhpmMpn8f0PmrW1ujZCH4Uxauu7Jq/Y1VLUBavQ7VCsaerrVAyES6iGOOth8q9iYkjj9AsR7UfdKbuYzVGJA1iQWtEqqm/E6u5W8k6O9UHouMmJofrPDCgTm7Yz9y/94@S5SQ/yCDoAtoNVvcqaf7bBG5kSJ8CCNGIrwGy/0pm6P9EOMqNEMTHNIXzg6tuGZwFV7qJLrr6OJFO@KKkra7IgWPPaEa33eqX6uYE8M1rAhbj6p7wW7rnXOdU29U1jJeqpFRSKK5YVbGpy6bB5Z45n6YTxHxEzjqO69ONvhzLGg/mTsgvmc3fuBhXuNfMmz@uflGOUks/@UYhMw5XUv0N/nyH36Gv@jvw5RMQL/UN@oLYhZJ@YVccATe/v7/w@eT7idGfvC9F13vLusGtacoju/3ytMNaFx29a/T6xPwKRSwCPjhxenc0qVQxGvLrqJOeK3Ad96I7XosVyynsdfKO8lQel70Oe4XGEza3PNXPjZDd6jrwMopiffeP9JQPAd8nLhaxfi6bor/v4gTJNe@O1OnLN28cx0rXruGP@COE3zwpihoi9bj5hNkRzcfHfw)

The function `r` does the thing.
The testing:

```python
s=r'''mi wile e moku - I want the food
mi moku e moku - I eat the food
mi pona - I am good/I fix*
mi jan - I am the person
ona li oko - He sees/He is the eye*
ona li jan - He is the person
ona li ijo ike - He is the bad thing
jan li jo e kili - The person has the fruit
jan li oko e kili pona - The person sees the good fruit
kili li moku - The fruit is the food/The fruit eats*
moku li moku - The food is the food/The food eats*
moku li moku e moku - The food eats the food
ijo li jo e jan mute - The thing has many persons
ilo li pona e ijo - The tool fixes the thing
sina moku e kili mute - you eat many fruits
sina moku e kili ike - you eat the bad fruit
oko li oko e mi - The eye sees me
mi wile e sina - I want you
jan li moku e ona - The person eats him
mi jo e ijo wan - I have one thing
mi jo e ijo mute - I have many things'''.split('\n')
print('\n'.join(str((r(j.split(' - ')[0]),
                     j.split(' - ')[1].rstrip('*').split('/'))) \
                for j in s))
```

The test output:

```python
([(3, 'I want the food')], ['I want the food'])
([(3, 'I eat the food')], ['I eat the food'])
([(0, 'I fix')], ['I am good', 'I fix'])
([(1, 'I am the person')], ['I am the person'])
([(0, 'He sees'), (1, 'He is the eye')], ['He sees', 'He is the eye'])
([(1, 'He is the person')], ['He is the person'])
([(2, 'He is the bad thing')], ['He is the bad thing'])
([(3, 'The person has the fruit')], ['The person has the fruit'])
([(4, 'The person sees the good fruit')], ['The person sees the good fruit'])
([(0, 'The fruit eats'), (1, 'The fruit is the food')], ['The fruit is the food', 'The fruit eats'])
([(0, 'The food eats'), (1, 'The food is the food')], ['The food is the food', 'The food eats'])
([(3, 'The food eats the food')], ['The food eats the food'])
([(4, 'The thing has many persons')], ['The thing has many persons'])
([(3, 'The tool fixes the thing')], ['The tool fixes the thing'])
([(4, 'You eat many fruits')], ['you eat many fruits'])
([(4, 'You eat the bad fruit')], ['you eat the bad fruit'])
([(3, 'The eye sees me')], ['The eye sees me'])
([(3, 'I want you')], ['I want you'])
([(3, 'The person eats him')], ['The person eats him'])
([(4, 'I have one thing')], ['I have one thing'])
([(4, 'I have many things')], ['I have many things'])
```

The raw thing:

```python
import re
p='mi|sina|ona'
v='jo|moku|pona|oko|wile'
a='pona|ike|wan|mute'
n='kili|oko|jan|moku|ilo|ijo'
pn=p+'|'+n
d={'p':p,'v':v,'a':a,'n':n,'pn':pn,'li':'li','e':'e',
   'f':'(?:(?:'+pn+') li|(?:mi|sina))'}
g=['f '+i for i in 'v,pn,n a,v e pn,v e n a'.split(',')]
ma=[re.compile('^%s$'%re.subn(r'\w+',lambda m:'({%s})'%m.group(0),i)[0].format(**d))
    for i in g]
s=r'''mi wile e moku - I want the food
mi moku e moku - I eat the food
mi pona - I am good/I fix*
mi jan - I am the person
ona li oko - He sees/He is the eye*
ona li jan - He is the person
ona li ijo ike - He is the bad thing
jan li jo e kili - The person has the fruit
jan li oko e kili pona - The person sees the good fruit
kili li moku - The fruit is the food/The fruit eats*
moku li moku - The food is the food/The food eats*
moku li moku e moku - The food eats the food
ijo li jo e jan mute - The thing has many persons
ilo li pona e ijo - The tool fixes the thing
sina moku e kili mute - you eat many fruits
sina moku e kili ike - you eat the bad fruit
oko li oko e mi - The eye sees me
mi wile e sina - I want you
jan li moku e ona - The person eats him
mi jo e ijo wan - I have one thing
mi jo e ijo mute - I have many things'''.split('\n')
x=[(lambda ph:[m.match(ph) and m.match(ph).groups() for m in ma])\
   (i.split(' - ')[0]) for i in s]
y=r'''mi   (subject)   -> I
mi   (object)    -> me
sina (subject)            -> you
sina (object)            -> you
ona  (subject)   -> he
ona  (object)    -> him
jo   (verb)            -> to have
moku (verb)      -> to eat
moku (noun)      -> food
pona (verb)      -> to fix
pona (adjective) -> good
oko  (verb)      -> to see
oko  (noun)      -> eye
wile (verb)            -> to want
ike  (adjective)            -> bad
wan  (adjective)            -> one
mute (adjective)            -> many
kili (noun)            -> fruit
jan  (noun)            -> person
ilo  (noun)            -> tool
ijo  (noun)            -> thing'''
from collections import defaultdict
d_=defaultdict(dict)
for w,p,t in re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*\((\w+)\)\s*\-\>\s*(?:to )?(\w+)',y):
    d_[p[0]][w]=t
md=lambda x:dict((k,v) for i in x for k,v in d_[i].items())
d_['pn']=md('on')
d_['f']=md('sn')
d_['e']={'e':'_'}
#print(d_)
mc=lambda x:lambda t:(lambda d:d[t] if t in d else d['_'])(x)
be=mc({'I':'am','you':'are','_':'is'})
hv=mc({'I':'have','you':'have','_':'has'})
vs=lambda p:list(d_[p].values())
tr=lambda x:[(n_,[d_[p][w if n else w.split(' ')[0]] \
              for n,(w,p) in enumerate(zip(i,pt.split(' ')))]) \
             for n_,(i,pt) in enumerate(zip(x,g)) if i]
#print('\n'.join(str((tr(i),j.split(' - ')[1].rstrip('*').split('/'))) \
#                for i,j in zip(x,s)))
noun=lambda t:lambda n:n if n in vs('o')+vs('s') else t+n
the=noun('the ')
the2=lambda n:'' if n in vs('o')+vs('s') else 'the '
v_=mc({'I':'','you':'','_':'s'})
a_=lambda s:('the ' if s not in vs('p') else '')
m_=lambda o,a:('s' if (a == 'many') and (o not in vs('o')+vs('s')) else '')
tr_={0:lambda n,v:[the(n),
                   v+v_(n)],
     3:lambda s,v,e,o:[the(s),v+v_(s),the(o)],
     1:lambda s,o:[the(s),be(s),the(o)],
     2:lambda s,o,a:[the(s),be(s),the2(o)+a,o+m_(o,a)],
     4:lambda s,v,e,o,a:[the(s),v+v_(s),the2(o)+a,o+m_(o,a)],
     }
from functools import reduce
f_={'haves':'has','fixs':'fixes','the one':'one','the many':'many'}
fx=lambda s:reduce(lambda x,y:x.replace(y[0],y[1]),f_.items(),s)
c=lambda s:s[0].upper()+s[1:]
print('\n'.join(str(([(n,c(fx(' '.join(tr_[n](*a))))) for n,a in tr(i)],
                     j.split(' - ')[1].rstrip('*').split('/'))) \
                for i,j in zip(x,s)))
#print('\n'.join(map(str,x)))
```

You can run it to see it passes all the cases)

Comment: I see I can squeeze out 50-100 bytes but it doesn't matter much for 1.9k )

Comment: This is very impressive! However, why is the output for **jan li oko e kili pona** `[(4, 'The person sees the good fruit')]`? What's with the additional wrapping/array/number?

Comment: I've edited your answer slightly to include a link to a testing site. In addition, I've managed to golf [-450 bytes](https://bit.ly/2C7auHa) with some very weird tricks, including fixing the output format

Comment: Awesome. I thought of ~300 bytes including `a if b else c` to `[a,c][b]` and optimizing functions. Very impressive.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>257</s> 249 bytes

```
OP€%59µ“:¤¥“ ı“¦1"ø“/“2¿“#“,3‘œiⱮ¹Ƈ’S,@ɗ>5Ḣ$¡"J1,3yƊ$ḢW;1,6y$1¦€ƲḢ,2,3;Ʋ2,1œị=3Ʋ¡+2¦=2Ḣ$¡€58,3iⱮ×7ḢƲḣ;Ṛḣ¥ɗL=4Ɗ¡2+2¦e€3,4Ḣ$¡€1,3¦7œị“¢ṇḃ#ṅ³©½øỴ£⁺Ṭḥ*4=LƤ`:[?SœGʠṂ4£¤ɦ5Ẉḃ⁵ƓOqȤ2MœṁṾġqÐU¤¶ṀẆ¶`ƝUḋ#ḳ#Ạ4Ẏ[`-ckṫ©4%ṙẎọkɲẠ¶{t}6ọ6Ṇ»ỴḲ€“the ”;Ɱ;@Ɗ€3,4¦¤K;11e”sxƲ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFdaxNBFH3fX7E06Ytukf1Iql1S@ybYSoVSRPqSIgtOdtO1NKUGEZIWG0lRhDzEioWmSRaKRejWhp0EFe42i/FfzP6ReGeTjQF9mLn3nrnn3DMzOcOyisPh6uNw/2I2dQ@uw9LnBWhBG6N4c4k7OPKM72FyB5cCP3FP4JLUsPSxXyPh5VegQSUsHa9JS4P6Yop5Z0lozDyUJbUYVJNYPtFlKV1MyuDgkMBFRFIkVQ9cRZL7NdY7yqiBC43bCjgZZUTHxtRdSeXqfn0eMU5r6ox@wgDtQX0lowVVaCicZGC3KmkTJk4GZz5S5v7PGK0w7yDB6Bu4gnP47nus9w2aYbnL6AXz2re0zErQyi5s3F/r1x78PmV0X4MmtAZOinXfIjUsXwe11e1fLeURqtIyoz9uGtv@h3V8qA6jJdY9hE42OFln3lGCeVcJ1j3VWPf9RnbumcnoFzjXZhk9RoT13pkDF4@h86rwOo1lmtFD6KEh5rnoHQ0XnhtiWDrR8e76UlAdXQ4caC3rsmzgyc7LwB0u6/yH5hajVr8iTBT8Cm5Ph8M8EfeIZYiGmLfNXQFLHqfKF/bWJo@5zS0BU9Eiom3acTqFkpwtEtMQEIpObBQxiUViAFljZKQZZRYZD@JD/1fETrh6rMoF87sFQyBWBHI5hLFF2CGYjnnRgKjvH5T75H4mtvJE@PsSvD12PWbFj2CP5oh7eO/pmo/5Aw)

A monadic link taking a list of words and returning a string. I’m sure this can be better golfed, but I was just pleased to have something that worked despite the various complexities of the English language!

### Explanation

#### Stage 1

Convert to initial pairs of integers

Note the first of each pair is initially 1 for pronouns, 2 for verbs, 3 for nouns, 4 for adjectives, 5 for quantifiers, 6 for verb/adjective and 7 for verb/noun

```
O                   | Convert to Unicode codepoints
 P€                 | Product of each word
   %59              | Mod 59
      µ             | Start a new monadic chain
       “:...3‘œiⱮ   | Multidimensional index of this in [[58, 3, 4], [32, 25], [5, 49, 34, 29], 47, [50, 11], 35, [44, 51]]
                 ¹Ƈ | Filter ones that weren’t found (li and e)
```

#### Stage 2

Determine meaning for words with two possible meanings; works because nouns can only appear in positions 1 and 3, verbs only in position 2 and adjectives in position 4

```
                 $ | Following as a monad:
          "     Ɗ  | - Map a link using the following as a monad as the right argument zipped with each element of the input to stage 2 as the left
           J       |   - Index along list
            1,3y   |   - Substitute 1s for 3s (words in the first position 
        $¡         | - If:
     >5            |   - Greater than 5
       Ḣ           |   - Head (i.e. if first number is >5)
                   | - Then:
’                  |   - Increment both items in the pair by 1
 S                 |   - Sum
  ,@               |   - Pair the right argument with this
```

#### Stage 3

Change pronouns appearing after position 1 to have 6 as their first integer (so that object versions can be used)

```
            Ʋ | Following as a monad:
Ḣ             | - Head
 W            | - Wrap in a list
  ;           | - Concatenate to:
   1,6y$1¦€   |   - The other list members at input to stage 3, with 1 replaced by 6
```

#### Stage 4

Insert ‘to be’ if there is no verb

```
              Ɗ¡ | If:
       2,1œị     | - the word type of the second word
            =3   | - is equal to 3 (noun)
      Ʋ          | Then following as a monad:
Ḣ                | - Head
 ,2,3            | - Pair with [2,3] (verb to be)
     ;           | - Concatenate to rest of list
```

#### Stage 5

If first word is ‘I’ or ‘you’, add 7 or 14 respectively to the verb number

```
      $¡€           | For each word, if:
   =2               | - Equals 2
     Ḣ              | - Head (i.e. if word is a noun)
+2¦               Ʋ | Add to the second item (word number) the following as a monad:
         58,3iⱮ     | - Index of mod 59 words (from stage 1) within 58 (I), 3 (you)
               ×7   | - Multiply by 7
                 Ḣ  | - Head (i.e. 7 if first word is ‘I’ and 14 if first word is ‘you’.
```

#### Stage 6

Swap noun and adjective or quantifier around if present

```
         Ɗ¡  | If (as a monad):
      L      | - Length
       =4    | - Equals 4
     ɗ     2 | Then (as a dyad), using 2 as the right argument:
ḣ            | - First 2 words
 ;  ¥        | - Concatenated to following as a dyad:
  Ṛ          |   - Reverse
   ḣ         |   - First two words (i.e. last 2 words in reverse order)
```

#### Stage 7

Use version of nouns and adjectives with preceding ‘the’ if they appear in the third or first position

```
           €1,3¦  | For each of first and third words
         $¡       | - If (as a monad):
   e€3,4          |   - Is one of 3 or 4
        Ḣ         |   - Head (i.e. if word type is noun or adjective)
                  | - Then:
+2¦             7 |   - Add 7 to the second item (i.e. word number)
```

#### Stage 8

Index into word list

```
œị                          ¤ | Multidimensional index into following as a nilad
  “¢...Ṇ»                     | - “I you he/wants has is  fixes eats sees want have am  fix eat see want have are  fix eat see/fruit person tool thing  food eye/good bad/one many/me you him” where / indicates newline
         Ỵ                    | - Split at newlines
          Ḳ€                  | - Split each at spaces
                      Ɗ€3,4¦  | - For each of the third and fourth lists of words, do the following as a monad:
            “the ”;Ɱ          |   - Concatenate “the “ to each
                    ;@        |   - Concatenate to end of list
```

#### Stage 9

Add “s” to end if many is used

```
K         | Join with spaces
 ;      Ʋ | Concatenate to the following as a monad (applied to the mod 59 words from stage 1)
  11e     | - Contains 11 (many)
     ”sx  | - that many “s”
```